# How to search a variable in the whole project in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Right now I only know how to search in one file.

How can I choose to search in the whole project (all files) in WebStorm? I didn't find the option in the menu.

And is there any shortcut?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is what I want to ask, not sure why your this post is in a low voter. Your this question is very helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Use:

```
Ctrl+Shift+F
```

Please Refer this link :

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Comment: I searched for a long time, your solution save my day : )

Comment: Thanks :)  QuestionContributor